# Showing Savon SOAP(xml) Response In One Line in Rubymine Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I've been using Savon as my SOAP client to request different APIs from Rails application. I've noticed that sometimes the response `xml`s are showing in multiple lines[see the pic] in console. But I want to get the response xml shown in one line. I've disabled `pretty_print_xml` and using `debug_level` `:info`. I've also tried with increasing buffer size(for lines) in rubymine but still is a no go. Please suggest me how can I get the `xml` response showing in one line.

[image: xml response in multiple lines]

Comment: _"sometimes the response xmls are showing in multiple lines"_ – try to narrow down "sometimes". There's probably a reason for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. By 'sometime' I meant to say, when the response xml size is very big compared to others. But I maybe wrong as I don't know the exact reason. The size issue maybe a problem to break down to xml to new lines.

Comment: are you getting this output in logs or where?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I'm getting this output in rubymine console.